# Removing SQL Rows from Query if two rows have an identical ID but differences in the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´m currently working stuck on a SQL issue (well, mainly because I can´t find a way to google it and my SQL skills do not suffice to solve it myself)

I´m working on a system where documents are edited. If the editing process is finished, users mark the document as solved. In the MSSQL database, the corresponding row is not updated but instead, a new row is inserted. Thus, every document that has been processed has [e.g.: should have] multiple rows in the DB.

See the following situation:

| ID | ID2 | AnotherCondition | Steps | Process | Solved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | yes | Three | ATAT | AF |
| 2 | 2 | yes | One | ATAT | FR |
| 2 | 3 | yes | One | ATAT | EG |
| 2 | 4 | yes | One | ATAT | AF |
| 3 | 5 | no | One | ABAT | AF |
| 4 | 6 | yes | One | ATAT | FR |
| 5 | 7 | no | One | AVAT | EG |
| 6 | 8 | yes | Two | SATT | FR |
| 6 | 9 | yes | Two | SATT | EG |
| 6 | 10 | yes | Two | SATT | AF |

I need to select the rows which have not been processed yet. A "processed" document has a "FR" in the "Solved" column. Sadly other versions of the document exist in the DB, with other codes in the "Solved" columns.

Now: If there is a row which has "FR" in the "Solved" column I need to remove every row with the same ID from my SELECT statement as well. Is this doable?

In order to achieve this, I have to remove the rows with the IDs 2 | 4 (because the system sadly isn´t too reliable I guess) | and 6 in my select statement. Is this possible in general?

What I could do is to filter out the duplicates afterwards, in python/js/whatever. But I am curious whether I can "remove" these rows directly in the SQL statement as well.

To rephrase it another time: How can I make a select statement which returns only (in this example) the rows containing the ID´s 1, 3 and 5?

Comment: How exact do you know you have to remove id's 2, 4 and 6 ?

Comment: What exactly is the logical key for a given "document"? And how exactly do you know which row is most current (or the order of entry) among all related rows? Is ID2 the primary key for the table?

Comment: Why can't you just select the rows with `Solved = 'no'`?

Comment: So all rows with solved = 'no', as in [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c0572bf11afac689d03401294e09735b) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to delete all rows where every id doesn't have any "*Solved = 'no'*", you can use a `DELETE` statement that will exclude all "*id*" values that have at least one "*Solved = 'no'*" in the corresponding rows.

```
DELETE FROM tab
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tab WHERE Solved1 = 'no');
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=32966e628753d7d313768ab216c4061e).

---

**Edit**. If you need to use a SELECT statement, you can simply reverse the condition in the subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tab WHERE Solved1 = 'yes');
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7639c19e28bd3fdc8e11e99ec17a121e).

Comment: Hi. Sadly I´m only allowed to SELECT rows. I´m not allowed to update or delete them. But thanks for the WHERE clause, I didn´t know that you could include SELECT statements in there. I´ll look into that!

Comment: Check the updated answer. @BGBVlC

Comment: Hi! I came to the same solution right now trying out the first solution you provided. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question correct:

`...every document that has been processed has [...] multiple rows in the DB`

`I need to find out which documents have not been processed yet`

So it seems you need to find unique documents with no versions, this could be done using a `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
Id
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Hi :) I updated the question hoping it´d get more clear. The issue is that there might be documents which have multiple versions which still do not count as "already processed". I´ll look into the HAVING COUNT(*) 1 command, which looks very promising!